# PHP or conditions not working in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

PHP IF Statement with two || conditions not working in Wordpress.
One by one its works but with OR conditions not working.
Can someone help me?

```
<?php if ( !is_single( array( 10 , 200 )) || !is_page( array( 5 , 77 )) ) { ?>
<div id="featured">
Salma Hayek is a beautiful woman.
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: if `||` not works, try `&&`

Comment: @mmm That's terrible advice. They have completely opposite meanings. A better advice would be to actually understand what you're trying to do, and use the right tool for the job, instead of just throwing shit out there to see what sticks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means "if it's not one of these posts OR it's not one of those pages". It always have to be true, because if it's one of these posts, it can't be one of those pages and vice versa. As mmm suggested: replace || with && to get

```
if ( !is_single( array( 10 , 200 )) && !is_page( array( 5 , 77 )) ) {
```

or put the negation around both:

```
if ( ! (is_single( array( 10 , 200 )) || is_page( array( 5 , 77 ))) ) {
```

which means "if it's neither one of these posts nor one of those pages".